# Standard HTML forms in Facebook apps?

Tags: php, html, facebook, forms

Facebook's recently deprecated FBML which means I'm having to do some extensive work re-writing company-developed apps. One such app had a contact form that was marked up using Facebook's FBML `request-form` object.

I've since re-wrote this in vanilla HTML in my canvas application, but upon submitting the form I can't seem to access the `POST` data in my PHP handler. I've tried `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_REQUEST)` and there's nothing in there resembling my form's controls.

Any one know why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if the page is redirecting? That could be the problem.

If so, this might help: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=34177#p297325